# Load docker image using docker engine api

Tags: docker

I want to load an image using docker engine api. I have an image tar that was created using: `docker save -o <path-for-generated-tar/filename> <image name>`

How can I load it using docker api? I am looking into `POST /images/load` endpoint on the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/). The documentation dictates that an image tarball is needed.

Is this same as what we get with `docker save` command?
I am trying to create an endpoint in postman which would do this but I cant seem to find how to pass the image tarball.

Kindly help me out with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it done:

`curl -X POST 'http://<ip>:<port>/v1.24/images/load' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-tar'  --data-binary "@image.tar"`

`@` here is important. The image tar filename must be given with an `@` at the start.